# Mejor forma de obtener Enum a partir de su valor ID entero en Java

Tags: java, enum

Un saludo cordial.

Tengo un ENUM de la siguiente manera

```
public enum EnumNumeros
{
    UNO(1),
    DOS(2),
    TRES(3);

    private int id;

    private EnumNumeros(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

En mi aplicativo deseo, a partir del valor entero, por ejemplo 2, que se me devuelva el objeto Enum: EnumNumeros.DOS

Esto yo lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
public static EnumNumeros getNumeroEnum(ObjetoJava objetoJava)
{
    EnumNumeros enumDevolver = null;


    int id = objetoJava.getObjetoNumero().getId();

    for(EnumNumero enumTemp: EnumNumero.values())
    {
        if(id == enumTemp.getId())
        {
            enumDevolver = enumTemp;
            break;
        }
    }

    return enumDevolver;
}
```

PERO

Me pregunto si hay una manera mas directa de lograr mi cometido, dado que los Enums tiene un método elegante para, a partir de la descripción del valor Enum retornar en ENUM como tal

```
EnumNumeros.valueOf( cadena_de_texto )
```

debería haber alguna forma mas elegante de, a partir del valor ID  en mi caso, retornar el ENUM correspondiente.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: `Una manera más directa` ,  creo que no lo hay :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defecto no hay una manera directa, pero puedes implementar un metodo estático en cada enum en el que necesites una búsqueda por algún atributo en lugar de su nombre.

En particular yo me acostumbré a hacerlo con un mapa en el mismo enum. Pero bien podrías hacerlo con un for.

```
public enum EnumNumeros {
    UNO(1), DOS(2), TRES(3);
    private int id;
    private static final Map<Integer, EnumNumeros> MAP = new HashMap<>();
    private EnumNumeros(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public static EnumNumeros fromId(int id){
        return MAP.get(id);
    }
    static{
        for(EnumNumeros n : values()){
            MAP.put(n.getId(), n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Toma tu like muchacho. Gracias